# PHP MySQL Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I got an error when I prepare my `$query`.
Here are the lines :

```
$query="INSERT INTO bm(title,season) VALUES(:title, :season)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
//$stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $season);
$stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':season' => $season));
```

I put the line with `bind_param` in `//`
I saw on others that could solve but error became roughly the same :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object**

So, I thought of my query but it's so simple I can't see anymore clearly. It's driving me nuts. :-/ I also tested the var `$title`and `$season` with an `echo` just before the `$query` line to be sure, like this :

```
echo $title." et ".$season;
```

but nothing is wrong, values are ok. These are strings var. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

---

Here is the complete code :

```
<?php
include("connexion.php");

// Get vars from previous form

//$id="";
$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$season = isset($_POST['season']) ? $_POST['season'] : "";

// Testing vars

if (empty($titre) && empty($saison))
    {
     echo '<font color="red">Must be filled...</font>';
    }

// Vars ok : could be inserted in "bm" table
else
     {
       // Protect - inject SQL
       $title=$mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($title));
       $season=$mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags($season));

       // Test
       echo $title." et ".$season;

       // Insert method

       $query="INSERT INTO bm(title,season) VALUES(:title, :season)";
       $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
       $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $season);
       $stmt->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':season' => $season));

       // Insert ok ?
    if ($stmt)  {
            echo "Insert ok.";
      }
       else   {
            echo "Insert failed !";
        }
    }

//Close connexion     
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your database call as follows:

```
$query="INSERT INTO bm(title,season) VALUES(?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
//could be false if prepared statemant is somehow wrong
if ($stmt === false){
    echo "Insert failed !";
}
else{
    //bind the params to the variables
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $season);
    //no parameters allowed for execute method according to the doc
    $success = $stmt->execute();
    //check for $success if true/false
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. But too bad I can't use the `:var` / `$var` tip. It was more easy to modify my query if I need all the vars in the `table bm`. Maybe with PDO ? But the code may be re-written from scratch... from what I have read about PDO vs Mysqli :-/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the most common used queing to fetch data from the database? The most commonly used is by using while loop for fetching data from the database right? I think that your approach(based on your code) perfectly works if you are using sqlsrv, but mysql and mysqli has almost the same syntax unlike from sqlsrv wherein it uses params to pass data, just my opinion :D

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the documentation on PHP MYSQLI (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) you will notice that FALSE is returned when an error occurs in the prepare.

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Instead of the call being from a mysqli_stmt object, it is from a FALSE boolean.
My assumption would be that the error occurs in your connection string if you are passing in proper variables.  More code would be needed to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I put the complete code. I got vars from a php form file.